# setInterval() with a count

Tags: javascript, setinterval

If possible I'd like to use to remove `count` and use an argument in `self.addOrbitTrap()`. At the moment for testing my code does something like this:

```
Bbrot.prototype.findMSet = function() {
    //...code
    var self = this;
    canvasInterval = setInterval(function() {
        self.addOrbitTrap();
    }, 0);
}

var count = 0;
Bbrot.prototype.addOrbitTrap = function() {
    //...code
    if (count === 100) {
        // Call a different function. That's why I use count
    }
    count++;
}
```

**Edit**: To be more specific, `count` is used in my code to count how many times `addOrbitTrap()` **successfully** runs (it does not add an orbit trap if a randomly selected pixel is a part of the Mandelbrot Set). After it runs some number of times, I call a different function (from within `addOrbitTrap()`). I would rather not use a global variable because `count` is not used anywhere else.

Comment: Is count referenced somewhere else that it is a global?

Comment: and what have you tried that isnt working?

Comment: Are you asking if you can add a parameter to `addOrbitTrap`? Like this? `Bbrot.prototype.addOrbitTrap = function(count) { ... }`? Can you be more clear?

Comment: Hopefully the edit is clear enough. I'd rather not have the global variable `count` if I can avoid it.

Comment: I would like to implement Strelok's comment. Putting `0` in `self.addOrbitTrap()` as `self.addOrbitTrap(0)` and receiving it within `Bbrot.prototype.addOrbitTrap = function(inCount) { ... }` does not give me something that can be incremented.

Comment: Oh you basically wanted something like an `instance varibale`. Just see @PatrickEvans solution below.

Comment: @Strelok, Not quite, what you wrote was exactly what I wanted `Bbrot.prototype.addOrbitTrap = function(inCount) {}` but I don't know how to make `inCount` something that increments.

Comment: You can alaways just return the incremented value. Like this: `... = function (inCount) { .... return ++inCount; }` But @PatrickEvans is right in his comment. Where would the input come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce `count` as a local variable inside `findMSet` that you pass to `addOrbitTrap()`; at each interval the value will be increased:

```
Bbrot.prototype.findMSet = function() {
    //...code
    var self = this,
    count = 0;

    canvasInterval = setInterval(function() {
        self.addOrbitTrap(++count);
    }, 0);
}
```

Handling the value is simple:

```
Bbrot.prototype.addOrbitTrap = function(count) {
    //...code
    if (count === 100) {
        // Call a different function. That's why I use count
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question, I don't know how `count` is being stored when `Bbrot.prototype.findMSet = function()` ends. I only need it within `Bbrot.prototype.addOrbitTrap = function(count)` so it works just fine, I just don't understand.

Comment: @asimes Your anonymous function is declared with `count` in its scope; after `addOrbitTrap()` finishes, upon invocation it can still access that variable; this behaviour is what makes JavaScript, well, JavaScript :)

Answer (score 1):

just make the variable on the object and use it.

```
Bbrot.prototype.count = 0;
Bbrot.prototype.findMSet = function() {
    //...code
    var self = this;
    canvasInterval = setInterval(function() {
        self.addOrbitTrap();
    }, 0);
}

Bbrot.prototype.addOrbitTrap = function() {
   if(ranSuccessful)
      this.count++;
}

Bbrot.prototype.someOtherFunc = function() {
    return this.count;
}
```

Comment: I realized that I could do that, but I was hoping to convert `count` to an input to `Bbrot.prototype.addOrbitTrap = function() {}`. I guess it is a bit OCD, but I have enough variables stored in `Bbrot`.

Comment: where would the input come from though?

Comment: Can I modify `canvasInterval = setInterval(function() { self.addOrbitTrap(); }, 0);` to do it?

Comment: see Jack's answer, he creates a local variable and counts it from there instead of inside the `addOrbit` function itself.